# Use Javascript to fade in/fade out

Tags: javascript, html, css, fade

I have some JavaScript code that applies a css style of `display:none` and `display:inline` upon the click of one of two buttons, but I can't seem to get them to fade in and out nicely, the instant display none/inline are a bit jarring on the eyes.

```js
//<![CDATA[
var submitcount42059 = 0;

function checkWholeForm42059(theForm) {
    var why = "";

    if (theForm.FirstName) 
        why += isEmpty(theForm.FirstName.value, "First Name");

    if (theForm.LastName) 
        why += isEmpty(theForm.LastName.value, "Last Name"); 

    if (theForm.EmailAddress) 
        why += checkEmail(theForm.EmailAddress.value); 

    if (!theForm.PaymentMethodType || getRadioSelected(theForm.PaymentMethodType) == 1) { 
        if (theForm.CardName) 
            why += isEmpty(theForm.CardName.value, "Name on Card"); 
        if (theForm.CardNumber) 
            why += isNumeric(theForm.CardNumber.value, "Card Number"); 
        if (theForm.Amount) 
            why += isCurrency(theForm.Amount.value, "Amount"); 
    } 

    if (theForm.PaymentMethodType) 
        why += checkSelected(theForm.PaymentMethodType, "Payment Method");
    
    if(why != "") 
    {
        alert(why);
        return false;
    }

    if(submitcount42059 == 0)
    {
        submitcount42059++;
        theForm.submit();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Form submission is in progress.");
        return false;
    }
}
// Credit Card info is not required if paying by PayPal, Hosted Credit Card, COD etc
function ShowCCFields(val) {       
    if (!document.getElementById('paymentdiv'))
     return;    
 if (val != 1)
     document.getElementById('paymentdiv').style.display = 'none';    
 else
  document.getElementById('paymentdiv').style.display = 'inline';
}    
//]]>
```

```html
<div id="paymentdiv">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Card Number<sup>*</sup></label><br />
            <input class="form-control dark" id="CardNumber" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="CardNumber" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> 
    <label class="PayCC"><input class="PaymentMethodType" onclick="ShowCCFields(this.value);" type="radio"  value="1" name="PaymentMethodType" />
        <span>Credit Card</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> 
    <!--<label class="PayCC"><input class="PaymentMethodType" onclick="ShowCCFields(this.value);" type="radio" value="3" name="PaymentMethodType" /><span>COD (Cash on Delivery)</span></label><br>-->
                            
    <label class="PayCC"><input class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ShowCCFields(this.value);" type="radio" value="5" name="PaymentMethodType" />
        <span>PayPal</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: try this [link] http://jsfiddle.net/eklimcz/u98Zw/

Comment: @I-amSam I'm dreadful with JavaScript, would it be possible to tune this to my specific code?

Comment: Try transitioning on opacity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're open to looking at other libraries but [d3.transition](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) seems to be what you're looking for.

[A nice descriptive quote of what it would involve](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/)

> D3’s selection.transition method makes it easy to animate transitions when changing the DOM. For example, to change the text color to red instantaneously, you can select the body element and set the color style:
>
> d3.select("body").style("color", "red");
>
> To instead animate the change over time, derive a transition:
>
> d3.select("body").transition().style("color", "red");

And here is a good interactive the tutorial [I learnt about d3 transitions with](http://alignedleft.com/projects/2014/easy-as-pi/)

Comment: The OP is not using `d3`, it's way too much to suggest just for transitions. Also, an answer should explain what the problem is, not just propose a different solution

Comment: Thanks for that, it seems pretty great. So I linked the d3.js script and changed my JS to `if (val != 1) 
     d3.select('paymentdiv').transition().style.display = 'none';     
    else 
     d3.select('paymentdiv').transition().style.display = 'inline';`. But it didn't appear to do anything.

Comment: You would have to use .style like in the question, i.e. 
`.style("display", "none");` 
and 
`.style("display", "inline");`